# org.apache.jasper.JasperException Unterminated &lt;c:out Tags

Tags: jsp

now, I make a JSP project using Netbeans,

in my host.jsp I using some tags like this:

```
<c:forEach items="${host}" var="host">
<tr>
<td><c:out value="${host.id}"/></td>
<td><c:out value="${host.name}"/></td>
<td><a href="HostController?action=edit&id=<c:out value='${host.id}'/>">Updates</a></td>
<td><a href="HostController?action=delete&id=<c:out value='${host.id}'/>">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```

The project is running succesfully without error
But, when I run it, the tomcat logs shows the output below

```
Jul 18, 2013 2:05:17 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: /hosts.jsp (line: 112, column: 50) Unterminated &lt;c:out tag
at rg.apache.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.jspError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:42)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.dispatch(ErrorDispatcher.java:408)
[...infinite looping...]
```

I was deleted the project, stopped the Tomcat, and tried to run the different JSP project,
but the logs still contain an error like above

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

I'm couldn't find anything to validate my assumption, but i don't think you can use single quotes on the c:out tag:

```
<c:out value='${host.id}'/>
```

should probably be:

```
<c:out value="${host.id}"/>
```

---edit---
This is not correct.  i changed to single quotes and it appears to have no effect.

Comment: I have changed it to double quotes, but the problem still exist,
whether its because of cache or something like that?

Comment: after I changed to the different tomcat server, now its working normally

Comment: Ok, i've tried testing and couldn't replicate the issue.  also, my answer is wrong, it appears that single quotes are fine.